# Sum of squares produced by statsmodels.stats.anova

Tags: statsmodels, anova

Inspecting the [source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/stats/anova.html#anova_lm) of `anova_lm` function, I find these lines for calculating the sum of squares:

```
effects = getattr(model, 'effects', None)
if effects is None:
    q,r = np.linalg.qr(exog)
    effects = np.dot(q.T, endog)

arr = np.zeros((len(design_info.terms), len(design_info.column_names)))
slices = [design_info.slice(name) for name in design_info.term_names]
for i,slice_ in enumerate(slices):
    arr[i, slice_] = 1

sum_sq = np.dot(arr, effects**2)
```

What it has to do with the sum of squares within (the sum of the squared differences between each group mean and the grand mean), which I expected to get from this function?